# How do I model this type of shape?

Tags: modeling, mesh

How can I create this shape marked in the picture? I just want to create the shape, I know you can add those details by sculpting but I can't even get the shape right. I have tried using a plane to build the shape but it looked so bad

[image: This is the artwork I am trying to create in Blender]

Answer (score 1):

Here are 2 ways to do it:

- Create a *UV Sphere* of 30 segments and 10 rings, keep only 1/10:

[image]

- Mirror it:

[image]

- Array it with an empty as *Object Offset* that you rotate 72°:

[image]

- Cut the hole, squeeze on the Z axis, change the topology:

[image]

Or:

- Create a 5 vertex cylinder, delete 4 of the faces, rebuild it with an *Array* modifier/*Object Offset* mode with an empty that you rotate 72° on the Z axis:

[image]

- Subdivide it a bit, cut the hole:

[image]

- Swell the shape with a *Cast* modifier:

[image]

From now on I guess you can continue in many ways (subdivide, sculpt...).